# Remove special symbols and extra spaces and replace with underscore using the replace method

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all special characters and spaces from a string and replace with an underscore.
The string is

```
    var str = "hello world & hello universe";
```

I have this now which replaces only spaces:

```
      str.replace(/\s/g, "_");
```

The result I get is `hello_world_&_hello_universe`, but I would like to remove the special symbols as well.

I tried this `str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]\s/g, "_")` but this does not help.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Your regular expression `[^a-zA-Z0-9]\s/g` says match any character that is not a number or letter followed by a space.

Remove the \s and you should get what you are after if you want a _ for every special character.

```
var newString = str.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "_");
```

That will result in `hello_world___hello_universe`

If you want it to be single underscores use a + to match multiple

```
var newString = str.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "_");
```

That will result in `hello_world_hello_universe`

Comment: This works for the single example provided in the question but will break in the general case. There are many characters in non-English languages which are not "special symbols" and yet fall outside A-Z. It's probably worth mentioning this caveat.

Comment: Replace `ig` with `gi`, said my eslintprettier/prettier

Comment: NOTE - This works even a-z is not there as in regex /ig - i = ignore case

Answer (score 7):

It was not asked precisely to remove accent (only special characters), but I needed to.

The solutions givens here works but they don’t remove accent: é, è, etc.

So, before doing epascarello’s solution, you can also do:

```js
var newString = "développeur & intégrateur";

newString = replaceAccents(newString);
newString = newString.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "_");
alert(newString);

/**
 * Replaces all accented chars with regular ones
 */
function replaceAccents(str) {
  // Verifies if the String has accents and replace them
  if (str.search(/[\xC0-\xFF]/g) > -1) {
    str = str
      .replace(/[\xC0-\xC5]/g, "A")
      .replace(/[\xC6]/g, "AE")
      .replace(/[\xC7]/g, "C")
      .replace(/[\xC8-\xCB]/g, "E")
      .replace(/[\xCC-\xCF]/g, "I")
      .replace(/[\xD0]/g, "D")
      .replace(/[\xD1]/g, "N")
      .replace(/[\xD2-\xD6\xD8]/g, "O")
      .replace(/[\xD9-\xDC]/g, "U")
      .replace(/[\xDD]/g, "Y")
      .replace(/[\xDE]/g, "P")
      .replace(/[\xE0-\xE5]/g, "a")
      .replace(/[\xE6]/g, "ae")
      .replace(/[\xE7]/g, "c")
      .replace(/[\xE8-\xEB]/g, "e")
      .replace(/[\xEC-\xEF]/g, "i")
      .replace(/[\xF1]/g, "n")
      .replace(/[\xF2-\xF6\xF8]/g, "o")
      .replace(/[\xF9-\xFC]/g, "u")
      .replace(/[\xFE]/g, "p")
      .replace(/[\xFD\xFF]/g, "y");
  }

  return str;
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/jonlabelle/5375315

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `\s` from your new regex and it should work - whitespace is already included in "anything but alphanumerics".

Note that you may want to add a `+` after the `]` so you don't get sequences of more than one underscore. You can also chain onto `.replace(/^_+|_+$/g,'')` to trim off underscores at the start or end of the string.

Comment: Why call separate `replace` when you can add `+` in first regex?

Comment: Because... good point. I was thinking of something else, I guess. Still, you could chain on a `trim`-like regex.

Answer (score 1):

**If you have a text as**

var **sampleText** ="ä_öü_ßÄ_   TESTED Ö_Ü!@#$%^&())(&&*+*+===.XYZ"

To replace all special character (!@#$%^&())(&&*+*+= ==.) without replacing the characters(including umlaut)

**Use below regex**

**sampleText** = sampleText.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()*|+-=?;:'",.<>{}[]\/\s]/gi,'*');

**OUTPUT :** sampleText = "ä_öü_ßÄ____TESTED_Ö_Ü_____________________XYZ"

This would replace all with an underscore which is provided as second argument to the replace function.You can add whatever you want as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

var str = "hello world & hello universe"

In order to replace both Spaces and Symbols in one shot, we can use the below regex code.

str.replaceAll("\\W+","")

Note: \W -> represents Not Words (includes spaces/special characters) | + -> one or many matches

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function to do so.

Just an improvement it also does replace the consecutive special characters as well.

```
const replaceSpaceAndSpecialCharsWithHyphen = (str: string) =>
    str.replace(/[\s~`!@#$%^&*()_+\-={[}\]|\\:;"'<,>.?/]+/g, '_')
```

Test string

```
This is__a__das_my%a%newest . ------ %#$^a?blog.for testing
```

Result:

```
this_is_a_my_a_newest_a_string_for_testing
```

Hope this helps someone.